# How to keep time format during exporting each excel row to its own csv

Tags: formatting, export-to-csv

I used this code to export my excel sheet to multiple csv files but I need column D to keep its time format of HH:MM:SS PM.

Sub SaveRowsToSeparateCsv()

```
Dim h As Range       ' header
Dim d As Range       ' data
Dim r As Range       ' row
Dim c As Range       ' cell

Dim i As Long

Dim ha2d As Variant  ' header 2d array
Dim ha1d As Variant  ' header 1d array
Dim hcsv As String   ' header in csv format

Dim da2d As Variant  ' data 2d array
Dim da1d As Variant  ' data 1d array
Dim dcsv As String   ' data in csv format

' init ranges with header and data
With [a1].CurrentRegion
    Set d = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count)
End With

' now lets go through each row and save it seaprately as a csv
For Each r In d.Rows
    da2d = r.Value
    ReDim da1d(LBound(da2d, 2) To UBound(da2d, 2))
    For i = LBound(da1d) To UBound(da1d)
        da1d(i) = da2d(1, i)
    Next
    dcsv = Join(da1d, ",") & vbNewLine

    saveFile ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator _
             & r.Cells(1) & " " & r.Cells(2) & ".csv", dcsv
Next r
```

End Sub

Sub saveFile(pathname As String, sText As String)
Dim fNum As Integer: fNum = FreeFile
Open pathname For Output As fNum
Print #fNum, sText;
Close #fNum
End Sub

How would I modify this code to keep the format of this column during exporting to csv.

I tried converting the master excel sheet to CSV UTF-8 to see if anything would change but it was the same outcome.

Comment: I ended up doing a second formatting operation after the export to reformat the time as I needed.